# convert clippos to ndc position in glsl?

Tags: glsl

I'm new to graphics programming, so sorry if I have used the wrong terms.

with clippos I mean:

```
gl_FragColor.w = gl_Position.z / gl_Position.w
```

I do this in my depthpass, how can I get the value of gl_FragCoord.z / gl_FragCoord.w in my postprocessing pass from the result of gl_Position.z / gl_Position.w ?

Answer (score 0):

That is kind of a silly thing to do, to be honest. `gl_FragCoord.w` is equal to `1.0 / gl_Position.w` so that you can undo projection. You ***need to keep*** that `w` value around somewhere unless it is known to be constant. *In fact, if anything what you really want to write is that `w` coordinate by itself.*

It will not be constant if you are using a perspective projection, then `gl_Position.w` will generally be `-eye.z` after projection. That value is mostly historical, in the old fixed-function pipeline the forward part of the Z-axis pointed down the negative direction in eye-space.

In programmable GL you are free to use any convention you want for coordinate spaces before clip-space. However, everything clip-space and beyond has a fixed axial orientation.